# Android Webview doesn't open deeplilink

Tags: android, android-webview, deep-linking

I am trying t render the following link on my custom android web view and end up in rendering failed. However, if I launch the same link on an external chrome browser it manages to go to either plaster or launch the installed app. Following is the link not rendering properly on my web view. I am not sure how chrome browser can launch this but custom web browser unable to launch the app.  `intent://?af_deeplink=true&af_engagement_lookback=7&campaign=None&clickid=1024ca7e19e0137d432d028a41f7c5&goalid_1=134&is_retargeting=true&media_source=involveasia_int#Intent;scheme=shopeemy;package=com.shopee.my;S.browser_fallback_url=market://details?id=com.shopee.my&referrer=af_tranid%253DJDFqzrWQLWOH0q5rYtLuew%2526pid%253Dinvolveasia_int%2526af_dp%253Dshopeemy%25253A%25252F%25252F%2526is_retargeting%253Dtrue%2526af_engagement_lookback%253D7%2526clickid%253D1024ca7e19e0137d432d028a41f7c5%2526goalid_1%253D134;S.market_referrer=af_tranid%3DJDFqzrWQLWOH0q5rYtLuew%26pid%3Dinvolveasia_int%26af_dp%3Dshopeemy%253A%252F%252F%26is_retargeting%3Dtrue%26af_engagement_lookback%3D7%26clickid%3D1024ca7e19e0137d432d028a41f7c5%26goalid_1%3D134;end`

Comment: Anyone can help ? :-)

Comment: I think you should url-encode the fallback url